# Fedora 14 won't see login screen after restart

Tags: authentication, config, fedora, graphical-logo

I'm working on a fedora 14 computer. It's a Dell desktop, and it randomly freeze the mouse disabling the left&right clicks at all ( well it responses to the mouse movements).

Yesterday it did it again, so I googled this problem, and ppl suggested it was acpi-related, so I switched to tty2 and **added two lines in my /boot/grub/grub.config file**.

```
apm=off
acpi=off
```

then I **restarted my computer**, it was **booting fine through the fedora logo filling up screen**, then it flashed black, and gave me **a screen with scattered fedora logo, when it's supposed to be the graphical login screen**. Here if I hit ctrl+alt+f3, it doesn't show the indicator but a floating square with a "?" as the only option, and it doesn't do anything when "enter" is pressed.

so this is going nowhere, and **I had to push the power button to force restart.**

*I did try going into single user mode, and changed the /boot/grub/grub.config file back to how it looked before, but it didn't seem to have fixed anything.*

any idea what is going wrong and how to get the login screen back? appreciate your help!

p.s. I've got a freely-distributed compiler installed on this computer but I don't have the install files anymore. So I don't want to reinstall the OS.

p.p.s. I made a liveCD USB of fedora16, can I make any use of that?

Comment: Have you recently installed any drivers? Things seem to work ok in single user mode with no GUI?

Comment: I haven't installed any driver recently. it might automatically detected my wireless mouse, but it sounds irrelevant. could it be any change of the display configuration?

Comment: does the LiveUSB boot up properly, show the expected user interface, and so forth? … Have you tried simply running updates from single-user mode?